# geting select data from database show it in dropdown in td

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i have html table here i having drop down it contain(600,700,800)if i select 600 in first td it will automatically update 600 to all country name same in first td.

my problem it show the 600 in all country name same in first td when i refresh the page, what i want when i select 600 i want it show 600 in all td regarding the country without refreshing the page ,i tried its not working anyone guid me ,below is my code

my html

```
<td style="width:141px" id="CPH_GridView1_route'.$rows['net_id'].'" >
    <select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" class="edit1 route '.$rows["net_id"].'" >
            <option value="-1">Choose..</option>';
    </select>
</td>
```

ajax

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.edit1').on('change', function(){
            $.ajax({    type: "POST",
                url:"xxxxx/routestatusupdate.php",
                data:"value="+$(this).val()+"&rowid="+arr[2]+"&field="+arr[1]+"&clientid="+clientid+"&account_id="+account_id,
                success: function(res){
                    data = jQuery.parseJSON(res); //added line
                    alert('Saved Successfully!');
                    $('#CPH_GridView1_route').empty();
                    $('#CPH_GridView1_route').append(data.routeupdate);
                    $('.ajax').html($(this).val());
                    $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                }
            });
        });
    });        
</script>
```

routestatusupdate.php

```
 i am connecting to db

$selectupdatedroute = "select route from $client_id WHERE net_id in ($supppriceid)";
$queryselectrouteupdate      = mysql_query($selectupdatedroute);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryselectrouteupdate)) {

    $routeupdate = $row['route'];
//print $routeupdate;
}

$result=array();
$result['routeupdate']=$routeupdate;
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Have you noticed routestatusupdate.php doesn't update anything?

Comment: Its updateing but it not showing in frontend,i showing only if the page refreshed ,i want to show it without page refresh

Comment: Edit the success function and post that code.  You also say in your question, "with refreshing the page"